# validating if statement not working properly

Tags: java, string, validation, if-statement

I'm trying to make an if statement to catch if the user of the program enters a value besides y or n for the question asked at the end of the program "Continue? (y/n): ". But no matter what the value I input "y", "n", or something invalid I get the message "Invalid input try again" from the console.  This is only supposed to happen when the choice is not y or n anyone know why it keeps happening regardless of what I input?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProductApp 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     //display a welcome message
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Product Selector ");
      System.out.println();

      // perform 1 or more selections
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String choice = "y";
      while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
      {
         System.out.println("Enter Product Code: ");
         String productCode = sc.next(); //read the product code
         sc.nextLine() ; //discard any other data entered on the line
         //make sure the case the user enters for a product code doesn't matter
         productCode = productCode.toLowerCase();
         // get the Product object
         Product p = ProductDB.getProduct(productCode) ;

         // display the output
         System.out.println();
         if (p != null)
             System.out.println(p);
         else
             System.out.println("No product matches this product code. \n");
         System.out.println("Product count: " + Product.getCount() + "\n" );

         // see if the user wants to continue
         System.out.println("Continue? (y/n): ");
         choice = sc.nextLine() ;
         System.out.println();
         if( !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") );
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
             continue;
         }

      }
  }
}
```

also wherever I get the message  "Invalid input try again" the program asks for a new input once but then moves on whether it's valid or not. it runs again if its "y" and closing if its anything else instead of asking a second time for a valid input.

Comment: You need to put ! condition there. if( !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") );

Comment: this didn't change anything y and n are still considered invalid

Comment: A side note on best (or at least widely used) practices: Most such (y/n) dialogs I encounter only treat "y" as yes and everything else as no.

Comment: ok I can remove the validation and the program will run I thought it was common practice to make sure the user entered y or n thanks

Comment: I still added an answer that might make your code valid (or so I hope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your condition is not working because you have **;** after your if statement.

```
if( !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") );
                                                                    ^^
```

Change

```
if( !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") );
     {
         System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
         continue;
     }
```

TO

```
if(!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
     {
         System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
         continue;
     }
```

Comment: still the while condition will fail since choice != "y"

Comment: Thanks this worked for making if statement work I was wrong about the problem being the parenthesis as I previously stated

Comment: I'm still trying to fix the problem this fixed the first one but not the second Simon's solution partway fixed that but now I'm stuck in a infinite loop as soon as I can resolve the issue ill mark as accepted

Comment: @ Simon:The code in your second statemente makes the program run also but I was looking specifically to make sure the user had to enter y or n just because it was what my teacher wanted and it doesn't force that but I managed to make your first one work thanks a ton for all the help if I could accept your solution as well I would since I asked 2 questions related to this code and you helped out a ton with the second.

Comment: @AlexChapp : I believe above comment is for Simon. In this case wheneveer u comment at start just type @ Simon...

Comment: @FahimParkar I'll hijack your comment thread for one more moment :) So Alex: No problem, glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

your condition is not correct it should be

```
if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    // choice is not y or n
}
```

Comment: This solution worked I think the difference between this and the other || statements that made this work was the way the () are structeure

Answer (score 1):

`choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")` **it will never be true**

**because choice may be either y or n but not both**

Answer (score 1):

Make it a while statement if you want it to ask until you input y or n. Otherwise it will jump to the big while loop and exit since the big one is asking for

```
while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

so, the inner loop would look like this:

```
while( !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") )
{
   System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
   //continue; //not needed
}
```

EDIT: Another approach would be to treat only 'y' as yes and everything else as 'n'

```
// pseudocode
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
   // do your thing
   if (!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))) {
      choice = "n"; // so exit
   }
}
```

Comment: Simon this makes an infinite loop but helps with the second problem of the program ending the parenthesis are incorrect though and i used the parenthesis from a different answer while making it a while statemnt

Comment: gosh dang it, I see it now :)

Comment: closed the loop by adding a prompt to get a new variable and making choice that variable to anyone looking at this with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));` to `if(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){`. Cause using `&&` checks for both condition to be true and this can never happen since `choice` can contain only one value.

Comment: just tried this it didn't fix the problem y and n are still invalid for some reason

Comment: Something funny that i did not realized until @Fahim Parkar answered is that your `if` statement ends with a `;`. How could i not see that. :(

Comment: I walked right into the same trap. That's why we don't get reputation scores ;)

Answer (score 0):

check your condition. it should be:

```
if(!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") ))
        {
        System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
        continue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) )
     {
         System.out.println("Invalid input try again");
         continue;
     }
```

Try this .